# Why is directory /home/david/workspace/ not present?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I installed Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS from CD on a new box, and ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This created a directory /home/david/workspace/

I later made an error and wanted to start over, so I reinstalled Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 once again from CD, formatting the whole drive, and again ran the three above apt-get commands.

Now there is no directory /home/david/workspace/

How could the first time create this directory, but the second time not?

Comment: I don't think that these commands made the directory in the first place :) But even if it did, I don't see why this is a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but "workspace" is not a default directory in the home directory.

The directories that re automatically added if `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.conf` has `enabled=True` (or for a per user configuration in `~/.config/user-dirs.conf`) are found in `/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`. By default these are...

```
# Default settings for user directories
#
# The values are relative pathnames from the home directory and
# will be translated on a per-path-element basis into the users locale
DESKTOP=Desktop
DOWNLOAD=Downloads
TEMPLATES=Templates
PUBLICSHARE=Public
DOCUMENTS=Documents
MUSIC=Music
PICTURES=Pictures
VIDEOS=Videos
# Another alternative is:
#MUSIC=Documents/Music
#PICTURES=Documents/Pictures
#VIDEOS=Documents/Videos
```

No, I do not believe Ubuntu did this from the default software.

"Workspace" I generally relate to 2 things:

- workspaces/viewports switching. Is default for Ubuntu but has no relation to directories and/or /home/$USER/;
- code editors. This does have a relation to your user since this is about editing multiple files in a project like setup.

Regarding the last option: software like Eclipse, Aptana can make a workspace directory but some do not do this in /home/$USER/ by default. Aptana creates it based on an INI file that has "osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Aptana 3 Workspace" in it. Eclipse uses "osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/some_workspace".

Where you create this is probably a 1 time question when you start that editor the 1st time (and a setting that allows you to have it ask everytime on startup).

To me it seems logical you also included some other software (and my bet would be a code editor like Eclipse) and omitted this the 2nd time.